# What is the upper limit on the number of dc2.large nodes I can elastically scale to in a Redshift cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

This is the documentation that I'm referencing below:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html

**Document 1** states that the maximum number of DC2 nodes that you can allocate to a cluster is 128. However, it doesn't specify the maximum number of a specific flavour or DC2 type nodes. I'm specifically wondering about `dc2.large` and it's upper elastic resize limit.

**Document 2** states that the `dc2.large` type node range is 1–32. It also states that the `ra3.xlplus` type have a node range of 2-16, and that "You can create a cluster with the `ra3.xlplus` node type that has up to 16 nodes. You can resize it with elastic resize to a maximum of 32 nodes." 32 is twice the stated node range of 16. There is no equivalent remark about `dc2.large` (nothing to the effect of *"You can resize a 32 node `dc2.large` node up to 64"* ).

I'm left with the question: what *is* the upper limit on the number of dc2.large nodes I can elastically scale in Redshift?

More specifically, can I elastically scale any dc2.large cluster containing anywhere from 17 to 32 nodes, up to a maximum of 64 nodes?